# Copy files based on existence of other files (Windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-processing

I have a folder of images in jpg format called "finalpics" and also another folder ("sourcepics") which has several subfolders containing RAW files in various formats.

I need a script (batch file?) that will copy all the files from "sourcepics" and its subfolders to another folder ("sourcefinal") only if that file exists in "finalpics".

As an example:

"finalpics" contains files called mypic1.jpg, mypic2.jpg, mypic3.jpg.

"sourcepics" contains files called mypic1.dng, mypic2.psd, mypic3.cr2, yourpic1.dng, yourpic2.psd, yourpic3.cr2.

I'd want the script to copy the 'mypic' files but not the 'yourpic' files to "sourcefinal".

There's over a thousand jpgs in "finalpics" but probably 40,000 files in the various subfolders of "sourcepics".

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look into `Get-ChildItem` and `Test-Path`

Comment: There's a reference to "mainpics" in your comment but it's not referred to in your example. This is a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry a type on my part - I've edited th epost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this PowerShell code will do what you're after; it will copy files of the same name (ignoring file extension) from "SourcePics" to "SourceFinal" if they exist in FinalPics:

```
# Define your folder locations:
$SourcePicsFolder = 'C:\SourcePics'
$FinalPicsFolder = 'C:\FinalPics'
$SourceFinalFolder = 'C:\SourceFinal'

# Get existing files into arrays:
$SourcePics = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePicsFolder -Recurse
$FinalPics = Get-ChildItem -Path $FinalPicsFolder -Recurse

# Loop all files in the source folder:
foreach($file in $SourcePics)
{
    # Using the basename property (which ignores file extension), if the $FinalPics 
    # array contains a basename equal to the basename of $file, then copy it:
    if($FinalPics.BaseName -contains $file.BaseName)
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $SourceFinalFolder
    }
}
```

Note: There is no filtering based on file type (e.g. it will copy all files). Also, if your 'SourcePics' folder has two images of the same filename but in different subfolders, and a file of this name also exists in 'FinalPics', then you may get an error about file already existing when it tries to copy for the second time. To overwrite, use the `-Force` parameter on the Copy-Item command.

I tested the above code with some .dng files in 'SourcePics' and .jpg files in 'FinalPics' and it worked (ignoring the yourpic files).

Comment: Thank you very much for this Robin, I've done a quick test with a few files and it does eem to work. It'll save me a load of time when it comes to running it on the full set of files. Just out of interest if I did want file filtering (say just *.dng and *.crw files) is that a simple option?

Comment: You're welcome, and sure. You could use the following: `$SourcePics = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePicsFolder -Recurse -Include @("*.dng","*.crw")`. This would only include .dng and .crw files in your list of source pics and thus it would only ever be these that were copied over (if matched).